# Special Characters are not converting using Apache FOP1.0

Tags: apache-fop

I have an xml document. I am converting it into pdf using Apache FOP 1.0. It is able to convert it into pdf but it is not converting some special charcter like *Δ,μ,ρ,α* and showing another output.

Expected Output = Δ INTRODUCTION   length constant (λ)

Account Output = # INTRODUCTION     length constant (#)

This is giving **#** symbol for unknown characters and when I try on other tools, I don't get these errors.

What is the problem with Apache FOP?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try using the character in escaped format in your template e.g.

```
&#945;
```

for the Greek alpha.  Refer here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03b1/index.htm